# Detect whether static library is a thin archive

Tags: c, linker, ld, unix-ar

When linking a static library as a [thin archive](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ar.html) the .o-files are not copied into the archive, but rather they are referenced with their relative path from the .a file.

How can I check if a given .a file is a thin archive or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I check if a given .a file is a thin archive or not?

```
head -1 t.a 
!<thin>
```

Eventually, `file(1)` should be able to tell you. My `file-5.09` just says `data`.